# MySQL syntax error on cascading configuration

Tags: mysql

I have this MySQL code for creating two tables, which are going to have unidirectional one to many relationships(configured with a hybernate):

```
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `msmail-database`;

CREATE SCHEMA `msmail-database`;

use `msmail-database`;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mail`;

CREATE TABLE `mail` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `usertoken` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `send_to` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `content` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),

  UNIQUE KEY `TITLE_UNIQUE` (`title`),

  ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `review`;

CREATE TABLE `file` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `path` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mail_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),

  KEY `FK_MAIL_ID_idx` (`mail_id`),

  CONSTRAINT `FK_MAIL` 
  FOREIGN KEY (`mail_id`) 
  REFERENCES `mail` (`id`) 

  ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

However, I get an error when I try to execute this from the CREATE Table mail, where it says on the line with **ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION** - that it's not a valid input and it shouldn't be on this line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can skip specifying **ON DELETE NO ACTION** as well as **ON UPDATE NO ACTION** as it is not required at all if you want no action on those events.

Default is NO ACTION if it is not specified for ON DELETE event or ON UPDATE event, so you can omit the same and check.

Have you used Tab or any other character between these two ? As another possibility I guess it is reading both as one command and fails to understand it. Put both on seperate lines and check again.

Answer (score 0):

I think the trailing comma causes the error, try removing it:

```
UNIQUE KEY `TITLE_UNIQUE` (`title`),         <-- remove comma
ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

Comment: It didn't help.